# Run a powershell script from cmd with elevated privileges and passing parameters

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I'm trying to run a powershell script from cmd with elevated privileges, but I need to pass a parameter to the powershell script. This is the code of the batch file I'm using:

```
echo off
cls
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -Verb runas -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%~dp0\MigrationTool.ps1 -ConfigFile ConfigFile.xml""'}"
```

When I use the code above, the script does nothing.

If I run the script without the -ConfigFile parameter, the script runs, then it prompts me to type the config file. Although I get prompted and then I just type in the config file, the script still doesn't work.

I did a little bit of digging on the Internet but couldn't find any solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you run cmd to run PowerShell to run PowerShell? May be there is a less complex solution to your problem. You might check out the [`runas`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc771525(v=ws.11)) tool.

Comment: The problem might be caused by the double `""`. cmd and powershell escape differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help, but I got a solution for my problem.
Please see below what somebody else recommended:

echo off
cls

PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Start-Process -FilePath PowerShell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "%~dp0MigrationTool.ps1" -ConfigFile "%~dp0ConfigFile.xml"'"

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm usually doing it this way:

```
@echo off

REM Calling script without parameters
REM powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File E:\scripts\some-ps-script.ps1

REM Calling script with option 'Parameter'
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "E:\scripts\some-ps-script.ps1" -Parameter
```

This should work in your case:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "E:\scripts\some-ps-script.ps1 -ConfigFile E:\scripts\ConfigFile.xml"
```

Comment: It's not elevated = as admin ;)

Comment: Sure, you're absolutely right. I totally overlooked "cmd with elevated privileges".