# Call a PowerShell script with elevated privileges via command prompt

Tags: powershell, batch-file, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

## Problem:

I want to call my PowerShell script with elevated privileges in a non-administrator command prompt.
When I manually open the Command Prompt with 'Run as Administrator' and enter the line:

`powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "Start-Process Powershell -Verb RunAs -Wait -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File example.ps1 param1'"`

My script PowerShell script runs just fine.

However, when I run it in a non-administrator command prompt, I see a PowerShell window appear for a split second and exits.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

## Tries

- Same thing happens, the window opens for a split second and then exits

[Run Powershell script via batch file with elevated privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48945292/run-powershell-script-via-batch-file-with-elevated-privileges)

```
runas.exe /netonly /noprofile /user:domainadm@domain "powershell.exe -
noprofile -File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\Powershell_scripts\New-
ADuser\.ps1" -verb RunAs"
```

- Same thing happens here as well, the window opens for a split second and then exits

[Run a Powershell script from Batch file with elevated privileges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48838760/run-a-powershell-script-from-batch-file-with-elevated-privileges)

```
powershell -Command "&{ Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList '-File example.ps1 param1' -Verb RunAs}"
```

- Same issue, the window opens for a split second and then exits

[Run a powershell script from cmd with elevated privileges and passing parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65679034/run-a-powershell-script-from-cmd-with-elevated-privilages-and-passing-parameters)

```
PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Start-Process -FilePath PowerShell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "example.ps1 param1"'"
```

CONTEXT: My PowerShell script is for downloading a NSIS Installer specified at param1

EDIT: Script code:

```
$param1 = $args[0]
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$installer = Start-Process -FilePath $param1 -PassThru
$installerWindowName = "Installer Setup"

while (-not ($installer.MainWindowTitle -match "$installerWindowName")) {
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
    $installer.Refresh()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- On Windows, an *elevated* process launched from a non-elevated console *invariably* runs in a *new window*, which *closes automatically* when the elevated process exits.

  - For *troubleshooting*, you can place `-NoExit` before the `-Command` argument, which keeps the elevated PowerShell session open until you exit it manually, allowing you to inspect any errors that may have occurred.
- In *Windows PowerShell* (whose [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) is `powershell.exe`), an elevated process launches with `$env:Windir\System32` as its working directory (fortunately, [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) now *preserves* the caller's working directory).

  - Therefore, using a *relative* path such as `example.ps1` does *not* work, and you should pass a *full path* instead.

    - If your script relies on the working directory to be the same as the caller's, more work would be needed.

```bash
# Note the `"$PWD\example.ps1`" part
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Start-Process Powershell -Verb RunAs -Wait -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$PWD\example.ps1`" param1'"
```